# Reading from a file directly into a 2D list python

Tags: python, list, logging, 2d

Here is the contents of my .log file

> Current Date & Time,    Trans,    Elapsed Time,   Response Time,  Trans
>   Rate,
>
> Wed Jul 18 10:03:1,   5,  0.37 sec,   0.00 sec,   13.51 t/s,
>
> Wed Jul 18 10:03:5,   5,  0.45 sec,   0.00 sec,   11.11 t/s,
>
> Wed Jul 18 10:04:0,   5,  0.91 sec,   0.00 sec,   5.49 t/s,
>
> Wed Jul 18 10:22:4,   12, 0.79 sec,   0.00 sec,   15.19 t/s,
>
> Wed Jul 18 10:23:0,   12, 0.56 sec,   0.00 sec,   21.43 t/s,
>
> Wed Jul 18 10:23:1,   12, 0.53 sec,   0.00 sec,   22.64 t/s,

I want to put these values directly into a 2D list in python, but every solution I have found just creates a list item for each row.  I want the value of a list slot to be one comma separated value.  EG row 3 column 2 in the list would store 5.  It's probably quite simple but I've been searching and searching and found nothing to do it this way.  Any help much appreciated.  Cheers.

Update:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "StressTestCompare.py", line 45, in 
    print data[2][0]
IndexError: list index out of range

[['Current Date & Time', '\tTrans', '\tElapsed Time', '\tResponse Time', '\tTrans Rate', '\tThroughput', '\tConc', '\tOKAY', '\tFailed', '\tData Transfer', '\tIP Address', ''], ['Wed Jul 18 10:03:1', '\t5', '\t0.37 sec', '\t0.00 sec', '\t13.51 t/s', '\t0.00 b/s', '\t0.00', '\t0', '\t0', '\t0 bytes', '\t10.2.2.55:8080'], [], ['Wed Jul 18 10:03:5', '\t5', '\t0.45 sec', '\t0.00 sec', '\t11.11 t/s', '\t0.00 b/s', '\t0.00', '\t0', '\t5', '\t0 bytes', '\t10.2.2.56:8080'], [], ['Wed Jul 18 10:04:0', '\t5', '\t0.91 sec', '\t0.00 sec', '\t5.49 t/s', '\t1609.89 b/s', '\t0.00', '\t5', '\t0', '\t1465 bytes', '\t10.2.2.57:8080'], [], ['Wed Jul 18 10:22:4', '\t12', '\t0.79 sec', '\t0.00 sec', '\t15.19 t/s', '\t0.00 b/s', '\t0.00', '\t0', '\t0', '\t0 bytes', '\t10.2.2.55:8080'], [], ['Wed Jul 18 10:23:0', '\t12', '\t0.56 sec', '\t0.00 sec', '\t21.43 t/s', '\t0.00 b/s', '\t0.00', '\t0', '\t12', '\t0 bytes', '\t10.2.2.56:8080'], [], ['Wed Jul 18 10:23:1', '\t12', '\t0.53 sec', '\t0.00 sec', '\t22.64 t/s', '\t0.00 b/s', '\t0.00', '\t0', '\t0', '\t0 bytes', '\t10.2.2.57:8080'], []]

Using print repr(data) It comes out like this, is it possible to get it in an easier to read format?  Even still it looks like it's all there from what I can see, so I don't know why i'm getting the out of range error.

Comment: I believe my updated answer fixes your problem .. let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module comes in handy for this:

```
import csv

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as inf:
     data = list(csv.reader(inf, skipinitialspace=True))
     data = [i for i in data if i] ## add to deal w/ blank lines in data file
```

would give you variable `data` with contents:

```
[['Current Date & Time',
  'Trans',
  'Elapsed Time',
  'Response Time',
  'Trans Rate',
  ''],
 ['Wed Jul 18 10:03:1', '5', '0.37 sec', '0.00 sec', '13.51 t/s', ''],
 ['Wed Jul 18 10:03:5', '5', '0.45 sec', '0.00 sec', '11.11 t/s', ''],
 ['Wed Jul 18 10:04:0', '5', '0.91 sec', '0.00 sec', '5.49 t/s', ''],
 ['Wed Jul 18 10:22:4', '12', '0.79 sec', '0.00 sec', '15.19 t/s', ''],
 ['Wed Jul 18 10:23:0', '12', '0.56 sec', '0.00 sec', '21.43 t/s', ''],
 ['Wed Jul 18 10:23:1', '12', '0.53 sec', '0.00 sec', '22.64 t/s', '']]
```

and `data[2][1]` (not `data[3][2]` due to *zero-based* indexing) would give you

```
'5'
```

a string, which you could convert to an integer `5` with `int(data[2][1])`

**Update**:

Added `data = [i for i in data if i]` to deal with possible blank lines in input causing problems in OP's updated post.

Comment: `[line for line in csv.reader(inf)]` can be written as `list(csv.reader(inf))`

Comment: always use `'rb'` mode in Python 2.x for csv files

Comment: set `skipinitialspace=True` to ignore whitespace after `,`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  For some strange reason, i'm getting a list index out of range when I try to print any row greater than 2 for example print data[2][0] gives the error, even though printing the list shows that there are 7 rows.  Any ideas why this is?

Comment: @user: Try `print repr(data)` to see what you really have.

Comment: @user1410747 Do you have blank lines in your file? I assumed that this was an artifact of your post. If so, the blank lines are causing this and I can adjust the code.

Comment: @user1410747 add this to get rid of the blank line problem `data = [i for i in data if i]` -- see my updated answer.

Comment: @Levon: csv reader treats '\r', '\n' the same and it doesn't support Unicode input on Python 2.x

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
>>> import pandas
>>> a = pandas.read_csv('input.csv')
>>> print a
  Current Date & Time   Trans  Elapsed Time  Response Time  Trans Rate  Unnamed: 5
0  Wed Jul 18 10:03:1       5      0.37 sec       0.00 sec   13.51 t/s         NaN
1  Wed Jul 18 10:03:5       5      0.45 sec       0.00 sec   11.11 t/s         NaN
2  Wed Jul 18 10:04:0       5      0.91 sec       0.00 sec    5.49 t/s         NaN
3  Wed Jul 18 10:22:4      12      0.79 sec       0.00 sec   15.19 t/s         NaN
4  Wed Jul 18 10:23:0      12      0.56 sec       0.00 sec   21.43 t/s         NaN
5  Wed Jul 18 10:23:1      12      0.53 sec       0.00 sec   22.64 t/s         NaN

>>> print a[' Trans'] * 2
0    10
1    10
2    10
3    24
4    24
5    24
Name:  Trans
```

Comment: +1 Wow .. the pandas looks very useful, I'll have to check this out!

Comment: @Levon: it's rapidly become the tool of choice for many Python data processing tasks.  I converted a set of scripts to pandas awhile back and there were surprisingly few headaches.  Plus, Wes McKinney often drops by SO so it feels like an in-house project. :^)

Comment: @DSM .. It looked so interesting, I tried installing it after I saw this, but my version of numpy is too old?? (4 vs 6?), but I will definitely check it out. I've used R in the past, this may take some those tasks.